# Script to Change Cell Color if any changes occurs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google spreadsheet that is edited by multiple people. I want to highlight the cell background color in red if any changes occurs in column 4-26 for multiples sheets.

Please Note:

In column 4-26 there may be value in number or text if it get changed from its original value or text then only we need to highlight it

Answer (score 3):

Set up and onEdit trigger in your project and select this function.

```
function onEdit1(e)
{
  var range=e.range;
  var column=range.getColumn();
  if(column>3 && column<27)
  {
    range.setBackground('#ffff00')'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works as expected. my apologies i forget to mention  in column 3 to 27 there may be value in number or text if it get changed from its original value then only we need to highlight it.

Comment: Please check off the answer if this is an acceptable solution.